# How to use passphrase protected private ssh key in terraform?

Tags: ssh, ansible, terraform, devops, digital-ocean

I am following this tutorial, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ansible-with-terraform-for-configuration-management, to learn Terraform and Ansible.

When I execute `terraform apply`, it throws an error:

```sh
digitalocean_droplet.web[2]: Provisioning with 'remote-exec'...

Error: Failed to parse ssh private key: ssh: this private key is passphrase protected

Error: Error creating droplet: POST https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets: 422 Failed to resolve VPC

  on droplets.tf line 1, in resource "digitalocean_droplet" "web":
   1: resource "digitalocean_droplet" "web" {
```

This is the code:

```
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = ["sudo apt update", "sudo apt install python3 -y", "echo DONE!"]

    connection {
      host        = self.ipv4_address
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "root"
      private_key = file(var.pvt_key)
    }
  }
```

That private SSH key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`) on my machine is passphrase protected. How do I use it?

Answer (score 15):

You can add the desired ssh key to the ssh-agent with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and then set the [agent](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/connection.html#agent) field in connection stanza to:

```
connection {
  host        = self.ipv4_address
  type        = "ssh"
  user        = "root"
  agent       = true
}
```

If using the `agent` field, do not use the `private_key` field. They will conflict.

Comment: If using the `agent` field, do not use the `private_key` field also. They will conflict.

Comment: @SunSparc's comment was the solution in my case, in addition to the main solution.